# How do I remove my exterior door handle?

Tags: screws, doorknob

The inside handle of my front door has a hole like the picture instead of a screw. At first, I thought I could poke the spring with a thin pin, but that was not the case.

I bought a hex wrench set to find something that fits the hole, but none of the hex wrenches (Allen keys) fit the hole perfectly. The hole is larger than a 2mm Allen key and smaller than a 2.5mm one.

The plate attached to the door cannot be removed because the hole in the plate is narrower than the handle. Could anyone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: That should indeed be a spring-loaded pin. Remove the handle to free the plate

Comment: That still looks like an Allen/hex in the pictures.  Try a 3/32" hex.  3/32" = 2.38mm. It might be the one.

Comment: Despite the ubiquity of metric wrench/bolt sizes, even in the US, there are still things that use SAE (imperial, fractional inch) sizes. I'm with @TedHohl, there that this is probably an SAE size hex screw.

Comment: If it's a screw, that makes sense. I'd be very surprised if it was, though.

Answer (score 7):

A little internet research revealed that 3/32” is a common size hex for Kwikset door handles. In fact, a search for “Kwikset 3/32 Allen” will reveal hits for this Allen (hex) wrench. The Kwikset Allen wrench is configured with a relatively long shaft (to clear a large door handle) and a short leg that is short enough to allow the installer to freely spin without hitting the face of the door.

From the Kwikset website:

“How do I tighten the screws for my lever that has concealed screws?

This model is a lever and requires a 3/32 Allen wrench to remove the handle in order to pop the rose plate off and expose the screws.”

You don’t need the special Kwikset Allen wrench, almost any 3/32” Allen wrench will do. As long as you can engage it fully and have enough clearance to turn the wrench to remove the hex screw counter-clockwise you will remove the doorknob.

Comment: Worth noting also is that the latch bears the logo of Weiser; Weiser is a sibling of Kwikset under Spectrum Brands Holdings, Inc. The two brands have many similarities.